# IOS: How to “unsnap” a slide over app

Tags: multitasking, ios

It’s easy to put app to the side in iOS 11, but how to un-pin it back? It always opens in this mini view.

I have an older iPad and I cant swipe down to put sideloaded app on the main screen. The only solution I could find is to sideload another app, but what if I don’t want anything there?

Just to reiterate - I want this app to be the main one. If I launch it from the Dock it opens in a slide-over state.

Comment: Have you tried swiping off screen to the right? That dismisses the app usually with iOS 11.  (Grabbing the handle is a bit buggy)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution that seem to be working is actually to go to the home screen and open the app from there.

Answer (score 5):

The OP is talking about an old iPad so mentioning “split screen” will not be available. Something like the mini 2 which is what I have and I have the same issue.

1. Start **Safari** as normal so this is the main app.
2. Start **Notes** by dragging it from the dock and onto the right of the screen so this becomes the **Overlay**.
3. Swipe **Notes** right and then have a full screen **Safari**.
4. Swipe from the right to bring back **Notes** in **overlay**

**Great but now I want Notes as my full screen app**

If I swipe **Notes** off to the side it just hides it. It does not remove it the **Overlay** mode so if I now swipe up to get the dock and select **Notes** it comes out as an **Overlay**, not as a full screen app.

Various solutions I found are:

- As OP said you add a different app as an Overlay. But I do not want another app in Overlay

Or

- Go to Home screen so no apps in view and then start Notes and it’s full screen **but** it secretly knows it is an Overlay so workflow is.

  1. In Notes full screen
  2. Dock to select Safari so get Safari in full screen as any other app would do
  3. Dock to select Mail and glorious full screen Mail appears
  4. Home button so no apps in view
  5. Select Notes from Dock to get Notes in full screen

     - You have to do this extra step of going to the Home Screen for Notes (the was used in Overlay mode and ios11 is stubbornly not letting go) because if an another app is full screen then Notes will come back as Overlay. For clarity any other apps you could switch to using the Dock would be full screen so yuck for this

Or (homing in)

- Annoyingly you have to have started Notes once in full screen mode to use this slight improvement as you bizarrely need that step to get the Overlay app to appear in the multi-tasking view so follow above to get that.

  1. Use can then use the multitask control panel.
  2. Swipe up to middle of screen and switch to Notes using this makes Notes full screen and as long as you switch via this back to Notes it is always full screen.
  3. So any other app you can switch anyway you want but always use the control panel to switch to Notes. Probably the most doable solution until you get an app to replace Notes in Overlay.

But one more I found

- Kill Notes and start from Home Screen

  1. swipe up to middle of screen to get the multi-tasking panel.
  2. swipe up on Notes to kill it. As before for Notes to appear you needed to do the start Notes with no other app in view at least once.
  3. Now crucially go to Home Screen so no app on view
  4. Start Notes and it will be full screen
  5. You can now switch as if it was never an Overlay

If you do the above but having killed Notes then go back to an app (Safari) and select Notes from the Dock then not only does it stubbornly start in Overlay mode but it also again does not appear as an app in the multi-tasking view.

I would like a list of apps in Overlay so I can switch between them. A clever version of the list we used to have and then swiping an app out of that list could be used to remove from a Overlay. At the very least it seems a bit of a bug that an Overlay app doesn’t appear in the multi-tasking panel until you started as view screen using hack above.

Answer (score 0):

If what the OP means by "unsnap" is to dismiss the app, then to dismiss an app that has been pulled up from the dock as an overlay this procedure should work.

**Note: iOS 11 is in Beta as of this writing and could change.**

There is a 'Handle' on the top of the app.  Tap and hold to swipe the app to the right (off screen) thus dismissing the app.  *Notice in the animation below how the horizontal bar or handle at the top lightens as it is tapped for the drag off.*

To be sure that when opening the formerly overlaid app from the dock is not again an overlay, swipe it to the left side and then pull it down to the left in split view.  Move the separator all the way to dismiss the original app (that was underneath) and now the app will open full screen when opened from the dock or when tapping its icon on the home screen.  See animation below.

[image: Dismiss overlay app]

Comment: Swiping off the screen works fine. How to make it the main app again?

Comment: You can swap it to the left side, then pull it down so that it is split then make it full screen.  I'll edit my answer.  Hope I'm following what you mean. Cheers

Comment: Oh I see, so basically you can only drop it at the right side of the screen?

Comment: Works for me on either side. Can dismiss by dragging off. This is beta software so results may vary

Answer (score -1):

only one app can be in slide over mode at once, so find some other app that you don't need and make it the slide over app

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  This answer doesn't address the question that was asked.  You should [edit] your answer to address the question or risk downvotes and having your answer deleted.  Please see [answer] for more info.  - From Review